# Error: Missing title - google calendar create or update

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm [issuing](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/477) a problem regarding the google calendar creation through the [node js google apis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis). The installed version is `25.0.0`

this function should do the job. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/calendar/v3.ts#L662

trying the official API test
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert#try-it
is working, but I can't get it to work using my code (is not working also with the update function to update the calendar).
This is my code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var auth = new googleAuth();
var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(user.calendarToken)
var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

function insertCalendar(){
  calendar.calendars.insert({
    resource : {
      summary : req.body.newName // tried also JSON.stringify({resource:...}) and JSON.stringify({summary:---})
    },
    auth: auth
  },function(err,newCal){
    console.log("calendar should be created")
    console.log(err) /* =>  output this { domain: 'global',
         reason: 'required',
         message: 'Missing title.' }*/
  })
}
```

The exact error dump is

```
{ Error: Missing title.
    at new RequestError (/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:34:42)
    at Request._callback (/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:96:27)
    at Request.self.callback (/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
  code: 400,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'required',
       message: 'Missing title.' } ] }
```

Just to mention:

before that call (insert) I've called succesfully this one

```
calendar.calendarList.list({ auth: auth },function(err,calendars){
  console.log(calendars) // gives the user calendars list
  insertCalendar()
})
```

Google says that the code (js) used to perform the call is

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert({
      "Su": {
        "summary": "Room 1"
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: YOUR_CLIENT_ID});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

So, also tried to pass `{"Su" : {"summary" : "cal1"}}` instead of `{resource : {summary : "cal1"}}` without any luck!

**Another try**
POSTMAN

calling the googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars (POST) and the json raw body as follows:

```
{
    summary : "Calname"
}
```

The calendar is created. so I guess is a bug with the google library. I will try to solve this issue by using a direct post call request.

Comment: what is in req.body.newName?

Comment: just a text. also tried replacing "Calname" to req.body.newName

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Comment: see the updates on question

Comment: Seeing as a Calendar name is called **summary** I would suggest that the error you are getting **'Missing title.'**  is coming from your code some place.  Calendar doesn't have title.  So this isnt a google error message its in your code some place you are trying to console.log title or something.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the error is printed by the `google-auth-library` as the dump says. and it's not my code because the `console.log` is printed inside the calendar insert callback

Comment: I have no "title" param, db field or variables around my code

Answer (score 0):

According to the google node js library you can specify request body as following:

```
const res = await gmail.users.watch({
  userId: 'me',
  requestBody: {
    topicName: `projects/el-gato/topics/gmail`
  }
});
```

So in your case it should be:

```
function insertCalendar(title){
  calendar.calendars.insert({
    requestBody : {
      summary : title
    },
    auth: auth
  },function(err,newCal){
    console.log("calendar should be created")
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Check [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#specifying-request-body) for more information

Answer (score -1):

Using **POSTMAN**

and calling the googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars (POST) and the json raw body as follows:

```
{
    summary : "Calname"
}
```

and the token provided by the library as the Bearer token, the calendar is created.

So I guess the problem is a bug with the google library. I will try to solve this issue by using a direct post call request.